# Are Thread.sleep(0) and Thread.yield() statements equivalent?

Tags: java, multithreading

Are these two statement equivalent?

```
Thread.sleep(0);
Thread.yield();
```

Comment: Even though they may be equal, it's always better to use yield() instead of sleep(0)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

No. The most obvious difference is that `sleep()` throws the (checked) `InterruptedException`. In practice, the effect may be almost the same, but it's entirely implementation-dependant.

I'd wager that doing each a million times in a row would take *much* longer for sleep(), since system timer granularity probably often causes it to actually sleep for a non-negligible amount of time.

Comment: that's a good point, something like sleep(1) may take much longer than 1 millisecond due to granularity.

Comment: @Michael You wrote " In practice, the effect may be almost the same"..By reading the Javadocs I am not clear about the relevance of the question itself and fail to understand  *in practice* how the effect *may be* the same for the two calls `Thread.sleep(0)` and `Thread.yield()`? Doesn't `Thread.sleep(0)` mean no sleep at all? If the answer is yes, then how can it be equated to `Thread.yield()` which is just sending a signal to the OS scheduler to schedule other threads?

Comment: @Geek: To get `sleep(0)` to actually mean "no sleep at all" would require extra logic to make it a no-op instead of treating the 0 like any other number, in which case it means "go to sleep and wake again immediately"- which *also* lets the OS schedule other threads. Since there's no obvious benefit from treating this edge case specially, I'd expect most implementors not to do it.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt I see the point of the question now.Thanks and +1 for your brilliant answer.

Comment: Treating 0 like any other number probably would _not_ mean, "...and wake up again immediately."  It more likely would mean, "go to the top of the scheduler's heap, and wait there to become runnable _at the next scheduler heartbeat tick._  If zero is treated like any other number, then `sleep(0)` potentially could sleep for tens of milliseconds.

Answer (score 35):

This really depends on the platform and version of the JVM. For example, under Windows in JDK 5 (Hotspot), yield() is literally implemented as Sleep(0)-- although a sleep of 0 is treated slightly specially by Windows as I recall. But in JDK 6, yield() is implemented as SwitchToThread().

I put together some information a while ago on [Thread.yield()](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/yield.shtml), including some implementational details that may be of interest. (You might also want to see the stuff on [Thread.sleep()](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/sleep.shtml) I put together on the same site.)

Answer (score 34):

Yield adds the current thread to the ready queue and allows other threads to run.  Sleep is not guaranteed to relinquish the cpu.

Comment: I think it's really more platform-dependent than that. See my post below.

Comment: `yield()` is not guaranteed to yield the CPU either, but an operating that doesn't cause both to relinquich the CPU is rather inconceivable.

Answer (score 18):

OpenJDK source (Java SE 7) have the following implementation for `Thread.sleep(0)` in `JVM_Sleep` function of jvm.cpp:

```
  if (millis == 0) {
    // When ConvertSleepToYield is on, this matches the classic VM implementation of
    // JVM_Sleep. Critical for similar threading behaviour (Win32)
    // It appears that in certain GUI contexts, it may be beneficial to do a short sleep
    // for SOLARIS
    if (ConvertSleepToYield) {
      os::yield();
    } else {
      ThreadState old_state = thread->osthread()->get_state();
      thread->osthread()->set_state(SLEEPING);
      os::sleep(thread, MinSleepInterval, false);
      thread->osthread()->set_state(old_state);
    }
  }
```

And implemtation of Thread.yield() have the following code:

```
  // When ConvertYieldToSleep is off (default), this matches the classic VM use of yield.
  // Critical for similar threading behaviour
  if (ConvertYieldToSleep) {
    os::sleep(thread, MinSleepInterval, false);
  } else {
    os::yield();
  }
```

So `Thread.sleep(0)` and `Thread.yield()` may call same system calls in some platforms.

`os::sleep` and `os::yield` are platform specific stuff.
On both Linux and Windows: `os::yield` seems to be much simplier than `os::sleep`.
For example: `os::yield` of Linux calls only [`sched_yield()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html). And `os::sleep` have about 70 lines of code.

Answer (score 10):

> yield() tells the JVM Thread Scheduler
>   that it's OK to give other threads
>   time slices. Usually the JVM uses this
>   call to activate another thread of the
>   same thread priority. In a good
>   preemptive multithreading environment,
>   yield() is a no-op. However, it is
>   important in a cooperative
>   multithreading environment, since
>   without yield(), one thread can eat up
>   all of the CPU.
>
> sleep(x) tells the JVM Thread
>   Scheduler to actively put this thread
>   to sleep and not run it again until at
>   least x milliseconds have elapsed.
>
> Neither sleep() nor yield() change
>   anything about the status of
>   synchronization locks. If your thread
>   has a lock, and you call sleep(1000),
>   then at least a second will elapse
>   before your thread wakes up. When it
>   wakes up it may decide to release the
>   lock -- or it may hold on to it
>   longer.

SOURCE: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=425624

Comment: Non-normative reference. Much of that is not in the Javadoc, and the part about 'JVM Thread Scheduler' has been imaginary for many years.

Answer (score 9):

The famous Brian Goetz's book "Java Concurrency in Practice" (published in 2006 but still fundamentally valid) says the following on this question.

> The semantics of Thread.yield and Thread.sleep(0) are undefined [JLS17.9]; the JVM is free to implement them as no-ops or treat them as scheduling hints. In particular, they are not required to have the semantics of sleep(0) on Unix systems — put the current thread at the end of the run queue for that priority, yielding to other threads of the same priority — though some JVMs implement yield in this way.

The rest one can find in the Javadoc pages.

Answer (score 2):

It's platform-and-implementation-dependent, and they are likely not equivalent.

The below snippet, when using Thread.sleep(0), most of the time gives the output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Whereas when using Thread.yield(), mostly gives:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

See snippet below:

```
public class CompareSleepZeroAndYield {
    private ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<Integer> getList1() {
        return list1;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getList2() {
        return list2;
    }

    public CompareSleepZeroAndYield() {
        list1.add(0);
        list2.add(0);
    }

    public void tryFieldLock1() {
        synchronized (this.list1) {
            list1.add(list2.get(list2.size() - 1) + 1);
        }
    }

    public void tryFieldLock2() {
        synchronized (this.list2) {
            list2.add(list1.get(list1.size() - 1) + 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompareSleepZeroAndYield obj = new CompareSleepZeroAndYield();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int count = 10;
                while (--count >0) {
                    obj.tryFieldLock1();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(0);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // compare above and below
                    // Thread.yield()
                }
                System.out.println(obj.getList1());
            }
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int count = 10;
                while (--count >0) {
                    obj.tryFieldLock2();

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(0);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // compare above and below
                    // Thread.yield()
                }
                System.out.println(obj.getList2());
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thread.Yield can give up CPU resource to threads with lower priorities, while Thread.Sleep(0) gives up CPU only to threads with equal or higher priorities.

At least on Windows platform :)

Comment: Is this related to the way Events tweak thread priorities to counter priority inversion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8274138/632951 seems to disagree with you (on yielding). Who is right?

Comment: None of this is required by the Java specification.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.Sleep()` has a slightly larger overhead because it creates a system that includes some kind of timer that will wake the process. (Depends on implementation basically)
Bottom line it will call a `Yield()` in the end.

`Thread.Yield()` Will just give-up the thread's turn, and gain it in the next round.

`Thread.Sleep(0)` might have an optimization to just call yield. (Again, implementation)

Comment: You said there is a silghtly larger overhead for sleeping. Which OS are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

> What yield() is supposed to do is make the currently running thread
>   head back to runnable to allow other threads of the same priority to
>   get their turn. So the intention is to use yield() to promote graceful
>   turn-taking among equal-priority threads. In reality, though, the
>   yield() method isn't guaranteed to do what it claims, and even if
>   yield() does cause a thread to step out of running and back to
>   runnable, there's no guarantee the yielding thread won't just be
>   chosen again over all the others! So while yield() might—and often
>   does—make a running thread give up its slot to another runnable thread
>   of the same priority, there's no guarantee.
>
> A yield() won't ever cause a thread to go to the waiting/sleeping/
>   blocking state. At most, a yield() will cause a thread to go from
>   running to runnable, but again, it might have no effect at all.

Source: SCJP Sun Certified Programmer book

Comment: Somewhat incoherent non-normative reference. How can it be 'supposed' to do something if it isn't 'guaranteed' to do it?

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not equivalent and besides the explanations above, 
I think it's necessary to check the Javadoc of `yield`. It seems not a good idea to use `yield` unless below situation meets.

> ```
>  It is rarely appropriate to use this method. It may be useful
>  for debugging or testing purposes, where it may help to reproduce
>  bugs due to race conditions. It may also be useful when designing
>  concurrency control constructs such as the ones in the
>  {@link java.util.concurrent.locks} package.
> ```

Answer (score -1):

**Thread.sleep()** and **Thread.yield()** do the same thing except that **Thread.yield()** relinquishes only to threads running on the same processor in multiprocessor environment.

Comment: What is the source of that statement?

Comment: This is the case in .NET i am not sure about java. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.yield(v=vs.110).aspx