# Code not working when running normally, but working in debug (eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm really confused by this: some of my code is not working when i run my program normally in eclipse, but it does wok when i run through each step separately using the debug mode.

Code:

```
public void showConnectDialog() {
    ConnectDialog connectDialog = new ConnectDialog();
    connectDialog.setVisible(true);
    //Until here, code runs
    while(! connectDialog.getConnected()) {};
    //The next line does only run in debug
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(connectDialog, "Connected", "Connected", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

}
```

The connector (is started (as a thread) as soon as the user hits 'connect' in the dialog):

```
private class ServerConnector implements ActionListener, Runnable {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (! IP_field.getText().equals("")) {
            if (! isConnecting) {
                new Thread(new ServerConnector(), "ServerConnector").start();

            }

        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialog, 
                                          "Enter an IP address", 
                                          "Enter IP", 
                                          JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            setConnecting(true);
            Socket socket = connect();
            if (socket != null) {
                ObjectOutputStream oOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                ObjectInputStream oIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                if (login(oOut, oIn)) {
                    isConnected = true;
                    setConnecting(false);

                }
                else {
                    socket.close();

                }

                setConnecting(false);

            }

        }
        catch (RSPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //If an exception occurs, setConnecting() will be true. This 
            //not good, so it has to be set to false
            e.printStackTrace();
            setConnecting(false);

        }

    }

    private boolean login(ObjectOutputStream oOut, ObjectInputStream oIn) 
            throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException, RSPException {
        //Send login request action:
        oOut.writeObject(new LoginAction(ActionSender.CLIENT, getID(), 
                                         getPassword()));

        Object obj = oIn.readObject();
        if (obj instanceof LoginActionResult) {
            LoginActionResult result = (LoginActionResult) obj;
            if (result.getResult() == LoginResults.SUCCES) {
                return true;

            }
            else if (result.getResult() == LoginResults.FAIL_ON_ID) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialog, 
                                              "Invalid password or ID", 
                                              "Can't login", 
                                              JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return false;

            }
            else if (result.getResult() == LoginResults.FAIL_ON_PASSWORD) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialog, 
                                              "Invalid password or ID", 
                                              "Can't login", 
                                              JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return false;

            }
            else if (result.getResult() == LoginResults.SERVER_FULL) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialog, 
                                              "Couldn't connect: \n" +
                                              "Server is full", 
                                              "Failed to connect", 
                                              JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                return false;

            }
            else {
                return false;

            }

        }
        else {
            System.out.println(obj);
            throw new RSPException("Server is not following the protocol.");

        }

    }

    private void setConnecting(boolean connecting) {
        if (connecting) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    connectButton.setEnabled(false);

                }
            });
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    connectButton.setText("Connecting...");

                }
            });

        }
        else {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    connectButton.setText("Connect");

                }
            });
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    connectButton.setEnabled(true);

                }
            });

        }

        isConnecting = connecting;

    }

    private String getAddressFromTextField() {
        return IP_field.getText();

    }

    private InetAddress getInetAddress(String fullAddress) {
        try {
            if (fullAddress.contains(":")) {
                String[] splitAddress = fullAddress.split(":");
                return InetAddress.getByName(splitAddress[0]);

            }
            else {
                return InetAddress.getByName(fullAddress);

            }
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            return null;

        }

    }

    private int getPort(String fullAddress) {
        try {
            String[] splittedAddress = fullAddress.split(":");
            return Integer.valueOf(splittedAddress[1]);

        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            return -1;

        }
        catch (NullPointerException 
             | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 
             | PatternSyntaxException ex) {
            //Returning default port value: 25566, because no port was given
            return 25566;

        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    private Socket connect() {
        Socket socket = null;

        InetAddress address = null;
        if ((address = getInetAddress(getAddressFromTextField())) == null) {
            return null;

        }
        int port = getPort(getAddressFromTextField());

        try {
            socket = new Socket(address, port);

        }
        catch (ConnectException e ) {
            Socket retrySocket = null;
            if ((retrySocket = retryConnect(address, port)) == null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialog,
                                              "Connection timed out", 
                                              "Failed to connect", 
                                              JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                setConnecting(false);

            }
            else {
                socket = retrySocket;

            }

        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return socket;

    }

    private Socket retryConnect(InetAddress address, int port) {
        Thread waitThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //Will wait 15(000) (milli)seconds before stopping with
                    //trying to connect.
                    //One second (1000 millis) is for debugging and testing
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

        });

        waitThread.start();

        while (waitThread.isAlive()) {
            try {
                return new Socket(address, port);

            }
            catch (ConnectException e) {
                //Do nothing, will re-attempt to connect.

            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

        return null;

    }

    private String getID() {
        return ID_field.getText();

    }

    private String getPassword() {
        if (getID().equals("master")) {
            return "masterPassword";

        }
        else {
            return new String(passwordField.getPassword());

        }

    }

}
```

`getConnected()` returns `true` as soon as it's connected to the server. The connector is running on a separate thread.

**EDIT**: I tried to put code in the `getConnected()` while block, and then it works. Why does it works then and not else?

Comment: Could be a race condition.  Can you post the code to `ConnectDialog`?

Comment: Do you evaluate any expressions during your break points? Those evaluations can actually change the state of your program (maybe you got lucky and it changed it into a working state?)

Comment: @austin The ConnectDialog code is 700 lines long, so i'll only post the code to the actual connector (which is still very long...) Hope your fine with it.

Comment: You could work with `wait` and `notify` here. The `showConnectDialog` waits until the `ServerConnector` thread notifies it. That way you can avoid the `while` loop and your program won't block a cpu core.

Comment: You don't show where your `isConnecting` variable is defined... is it defined as `volatile`?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

Comment: I confirm, the thread.sleep does work on that case i used it but with 20 milisecs as parameter, thanks a lot for your help !
hope this gonna help someone else in the future

Answer (score 5):

I had the same Problem, but with some more specification. The code was working fine in 32bit but I had this issue in 64bit (I am using native library so I need to maintain both).

The solution I found is to add Thread.sleep() in the while loop. I don't know why it works, so your guess is as good as mine.

A better solution would probably to implement an [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) instead of having an infinite loop. But that would require some re-factoring.

Answer (score 3):

Using `Thread.sleep()`, as the other answers have suggested, should solve the problem but it is not a very good approach. Instead, we should be using `Thread.yield()`.

Why `yield` and not `sleep`?

Refer:
[Difference between Thread.Sleep(0) and Thread.Yield()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956961/difference-between-thread-sleep0-and-thread-yield) and [Are Thread.sleep(0) and Thread.yield() statements equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600572/are-thread-sleep0-and-thread-yield-statements-equivalent)

Why this works?

When we just run the threads, the OS puts them to "idle" state and when it is expected to "wake-up", it does not. On the other hand, in debug mode, we have a controlled environment. The OS has little control over it as everything goes on step-by-step, slowly. If we run the debug a few times without any break-points, after a few successful runs, we should see the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem with a "while" loop that wouldn't run and that loop was my main routine. How I got the loop to run was that the very first thing that was done in the loop was a sleep:

```
    try
        {Thread.sleep(0);}
    catch (Exception e)
        {e.printStackTrace();}
```

This was enough to get everything going.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem in UIAutomator with UiObject2 wait(Until.findObject(),20) .

Thread.yield() - works for me