# Code running fine in debug mode, but stops when run normally (eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

I found this link on SO:

[Code not working when running normally, but working in debug (eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070627/code-not-working-when-running-normally-but-working-in-debug-eclipse)

and on seeing the answers, added a `Thread.sleep(0)` inside my while loop and it works.

The question is "why?". Also, is this problem specific to `Eclipse`?

Comment: Do you know what `Thread.sleep(0)` means?

Comment: Post the code for us to "debug"

Comment: The reason is now clear to me, thanks to the hint by TheLostMind :) And @JamesJithin, it worked fine when I added sleep(). So, my code was not an issue to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It definitely is not specific to Eclipse.  It's a threading issue and can happen in any program using threads that rely on each other.  Debug makes the timing issue go away because you are essentially performing a sleep by slowing everything down to walk the code.

If you run debug multiple times with no stops you might find that your failure shows up in a few of the runs.

Making a thread sleep gives the other threads time to "catch up" and complete whatever task the sleeping thread is waiting on.

Comment: Saved me another two hours of searching what's wrong with my code.