# Thread.Yield() causes CPU spikes?

Tags: .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, yield

In a project of mine, I noticed the server spiking in CPU usage as the number of clients connected increase.

> 10 clients: 0% mostly, spikes to 7% randomly.
>   15 clients: 0% mostly, spikes to 10% randomly.
>   25 clients: 10% mostly, spikes to 60% randomly.
>   50 clients: 50% mostly, spikes to 60%, CPU is overall at 100% (due to gameservers).
>   (Note: there are 8 logical cores on the CPU)

I narrowed down the problem to [`Thread.Yield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.yield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), on this line: https://github.com/vercas/vProto/blob/master/vProto/Base%20Client/Package%20Sending.cs#L121
As soon as I comment that line out, CPU usage stays at 0% constantly even with 100 clients!

Why is `Thread.Yield` doing this?

Comment: Do you *also* comment out the `Thread.Sleep` line when commenting out `Thread.Yield`? That is, I don't believe the issue is strictly related to `Thread.Yield` "causing the spikes", but rather that `Thread.Sleep(10)` actually *reduces* the frequency of the loop and/or *contention*, and thus CPU usage consumed per thread..

Comment: No actual sending was happening during my test. Swapping a few pointers couldn't have been that expensive...

Comment: I don't doubt it's related to the scheduling in *some* fashion, but I suspect it's *not* simply because of a "context switch". I really do think it might be related to lock contention or other degenerate case with the scheduler. Does `Thread.Sleep(1)` also exhibit similar spikes? If not, what about throughput?

Comment: I could easily test by placing the sleep in an `else` statement attached to the previous if (checking if there are any queued packages). As for throughput, there is only a body-less package sent every 30 seconds per client (and per-thread). The same throughput exists now and doesn't exhibit the same problem.

Comment: 700 clients and still 0% CPU usage.

Comment: That's with removing the lock or using Thread.Sleep(1) only or a combination or ..?

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(1)`. 1200 clients and only goes to 1% sometimes. I'm benchmarking with the help of a friend. So far, results are very satisfying. Pings are ~70 for me. That's less than I get to our gameservers (on the same machine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to the way Thread.Yield releases processing. It forces the current process thread to release prematurely. This in turn sends out messages to all other processes telling them to do their own thing. Switching process context is expensive in terms of swapping out memory, loading cached processes, and moving through the process list out of sequence.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.yield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If this method succeeds, the rest of the thread's current time slice is yielded. The operating system schedules the calling thread for another time slice, according to its priority and the status of other threads that are available to run.
>
> Yielding is limited to the processor that is executing the calling thread. The operating system will not switch execution to another processor, even if that processor is idle or is running a thread of lower priority. If there are no other threads that are ready to execute on the current processor, the operating system does not yield execution, and this method returns false.
>
> This method is equivalent to using platform invoke to call the native Win32 SwitchToThread function. You should call the Yield method instead of using platform invoke, because platform invoke bypasses any custom threading behavior the host has requested.

---

**UPDATE**

There has been some challenge to the statement that Thread.Yield causes expensive context switching. Here are additional references:

[Difference between Thread.Sleep0 and Thread.Yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956961/difference-between-thread-sleep0-and-thread-yield)

[Threading in C# - Joseph Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

[MSDN - About Processes and Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[MSDN - Multitasking Considerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> The recommended guideline is to use as few threads as possible, thereby minimizing the use of system resources. This improves performance. Multitasking has resource requirements and potential conflicts to be considered when designing your application. The resource requirements are as follows:
>
> - The system consumes memory for the context information required by both processes and threads. Therefore, the number of processes and threads that can be created is limited by available memory.
> - Keeping track of a large number of threads consumes significant processor time. If there are too many threads, most of them will not be able to make significant progress. If most of the current threads are in one process, threads in other processes are scheduled less frequently.

Comment: And when the Windows scheduler does this, it's cheap as dirt (performance-wise), but when I do it, it eats away half a CPU core worth of performance..?

Comment: Pretty much. Most of the expense is the forced swapping in and out of memory.

Comment: Don't do a Thread.Sleep(0) as it will do the exact same thing as Thread.Yield().

Comment: I am aware. I use 1 millisecond. If the system it runs on happens to have higher thread resolution enabled, it'll be a gain. The otherwise extra 14 milliseconds won't hurt. I hope.

Comment: I'm not sure how the MSDN link/quote addresses the spikes. Since windows is a *preemptive* OS, it will "expensive switching process context" anyway, even without Thread.Yield, will it not? (In fact, it does this many, many times/second already on my very-interactive desktop.)

Comment: I wish I could peak into Thread.YieldInternal in mscorlib.dll!

Comment: Also, since `Thread.Sleep(10)` causes an "expensive switching process context" (albeit one that says "don't call me again before 10ms"), *why* would only `Thread.Yield` be affected with these spikes when not `Thread.Sleep(10)`? That is, I am challenging the assertion that the spikes are caused by "switching process context", as it happens in both cases.

Comment: When .NET invokes the Win 32 thread switch, I am fairly certain that doing so also pauses the .NET runtime. If there was a method for just pausing/yielding to other .NET threads, it would cut down a lot of swapping.

Comment: Thread sleep has at least two paths of processing. If you perform a sleep(0), it does exactly the same thing as yield. If you put a number > 0, it runs a different code path that doesn't always perform process switching.

Comment: How could it sleep without performing a context switch? Have an external reference/resource?

Comment: Oh, I see. That's what I *don't like* about this answer - it talks about *processes*, which I refute. Also, only `Thread.Yield` *may not* yield thread control, while `Thread.Sleep(x; x>0)` *will always* yield the process (which again is an argument *against* the claim in this reply). The MSDN link talks about *processors* (not *processes*), which may be a factor.

Comment: You seem to be conflating two very different things - context switching and memory swapping. Context switching does not necessarily require memory swapping, so the reasoning behind your answer would seem to break down.

Answer (score 2):

I *don't know* why this usage of Thread.Yield/Sleep<sup>1</sup> might cause these spikes, however I refute that it is caused merely by "context switching". (I've no doubt it relates, but a stronger explanation is required.)

[Thread.Sleep or Thread.Yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480912/thread-sleep-or-thread-yield) seems to give a satisfactory answer for when Yield and Sleep are used *exclusively* - basically that Yield, like Sleep(0), might *not* yield - although it may not directly apply the case of "Yield and Sleep if required"<sup>1</sup> vs "always Sleep without trying to yield Yield", as presented in this question.

<sup>1</sup>The original CPU-spiking code presented used: `if (!Thread.Yield()) Thread.Sleep(10);`. (This is an example of why it is *important* to include relevant code in questions.)

My arguments *against* context switching being the problem follow.

---

1. Windows use [preemptive scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)) and context switches dozens of times per second, even when threads don't actively yield.
2. Thread.Sleep(x), where x > 0, will *always* [cause a context-switch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3257708/2864740); yet `Thread.Sleep(1)` is reported to *not* cause such spikes.
3. Thread.Yield *might not* cause a context switch, yet it is reported to cause spikes.

   > The operating system (read: Thread.Yield) will *not* switch execution if..

Comment: Well, as I mentioned before, the spikes were happening while sending nothing more than two packages every 30 seconds, and constant CPU usage increased exponentially after ~300 clients. All the updates of that file after removing `Thread.Yield()` never produced a spike, even under load. Especially the new `ThreadPool`-based method, it is amazing. I saturated the network connection before getting to 2% CPU usage. (~1800 vProto clients to 1 vProto server + ~250 clients connected to gameservers on the same server machine) Still, I'd love to get to the bottom of this problem.