# How to use Interlocked.CompareExchange as an inter-process lock?

Tags: c#, concurrency, synchronization, interlocked

I'm obviously doing something wrong here. I always get different number running this code:

```cs
var counter = new ConcurrentCounter();

var count = counter.Count();

Console.WriteLine(count);

public class ConcurrentCounter
{
    private int _id;
    private int _lock;
    private int _counter;

    public int Count()
    {
        var threads = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new Thread(Worker)).ToArray();

        foreach (var thread in threads) thread.Start();

        foreach (var thread in threads) thread.Join();

        return _counter;
    }

    private void Worker()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var id = Interlocked.Increment(ref _id);

                var current = Volatile.Read(ref _lock);

                //Begin a locked block
                if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _lock, id, current) == current)
                {
                    var value = Volatile.Read(ref _counter);

                    Volatile.Write(ref _counter, value + 1);

                    //Release the lock
                    Volatile.Write(ref _lock, current);

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong here? How can I get a working lock using Interlocked.CompareExchange? I cannot use usual C# lock as it will be used for inter-process shared memory lock.

Comment: If you want to share "lock" between processes you can try `Mutex` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=net-7.0

Comment: For inter-process lock you can use a named [`Mutex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex). How is it possible for the `Interlocked.CompareExchange` to work across process boundaries?

Comment: I would suspect that the wild increases of `id` arrived at the same number in two workers somehow. If you want a unique id, either assign it to the workers as a parameter or use something like thread id. Or make the lock a binary value (locked/not locked).

Comment: I will try Mutex if CompareExchange won't work, thank you. I hoped that I can use this way with MemoryMappedFile and work with pointers.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Atomics like CAS and futexes work across processes if the memory used as lock is shared between them.

Comment: @CodesInChaos interesting, I didn't know that. Maybe someone could post a complete implementation of a custom cross-process `Mutex` based on this idea, with two methods `TryAcquire` and `Release`.

Comment: @TheodorZouliasI `TryAquire`+`Release` work using simple atomic operations. I think recent versions of Rust implement their mutex on top of futex on Linux and it supports blocking `Aquire` as well (proper blocking, not unlimited spinning).

Comment: @CodesInChaos yep, it has to be simple, so that the emphasis is on the cross-process sharing of the memory. That's the part I would be interested to see!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that every time a CAS fails, you will retrieve the `_lock` value again, so the next CAS will definitely succeed, leading to this useless comparison. You need to block the thread until you've released the lock.

This is actually a simple spin lock, you do not need additional `_id` to implement the lock, you only need to define two values:

```
int lockValue = 1;
int freeValue = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    //Begin a locked block
    while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _lock, lockValue, freeValue) != freeValue)
        Thread.Sleep(0);

    var value = Volatile.Read(ref _counter);

    Volatile.Write(ref _counter, value + 1);

    //Release the lock
    Volatile.Write(ref _lock, freeValue);
}
```

Comment: I still don't understand the reason, but it works! Is it really necessary to call Thread.Sleep?

Comment: @user1576055 On a multi core system, not really. But without it the thread wastes CPU time while waiting. Optimal wait patterns for spin locks a are complicated topic, and if possible I'd switch to a futex if spinning doesn't succeed after a short while.

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956961/difference-between-thread-sleep0-and-thread-yield) about different ways of yielding control to another thread.