# Threads affected by Thread.yield()?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Here is a multi-threaded HelloWorld:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread myThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Hello World from new thread");
            }
        };
        myThread.start();
        Thread.yield();
        System.out.println("Hello from main thread");
        myThread.join();
    }
}
```

As I understand, after the `myThread.start()`, there will be two threads running. One is the main thread, and the other is the newly-created `myThread`. Then, which thread is referred to in the `Thread.yield()`?

I checked the Java SE6 Doc, which says

> Thread.yield(): Causes the currently executing thread object to
>   temporarily pause and allow other threads to execute

But in the codes, I can't see clearly what the `currently excuting thread` is, it looks that **both threads are running at the same time**.

Isn't it be more clear to say `myThread.yield()` instead of `Thread.yield()`? Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: In your context, `Thread.yield` will yield the "main" thread in which `main` is running

Comment: Also see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600572/are-thread-sleep0-and-thread-yield-statements-equivalent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With "current thread" in this context, the Javadoc means "the thread that called the method `Thread.yield()`"

In your case, this is the main thread that started your application.

As the Javadoc explains, there is normally no need to call `Thread.yield()`. It's not required to do anything:

> A hint to the scheduler that the current thread is willing to yield
>   its current use of a processor. The scheduler is free to ignore this
>   hint.

It does seem to do something, at least up to Java 6 - couldn't find a reference for Java 7/8.

Windows:

> The Hotspot VM now implements `Thread.yield()` using the Windows
>   `SwitchToThread()` API call. This call makes the current thread give up
>   its current timeslice, but not its entire quantum.

Linux:

> Under Linux, Hotspot simply calls `sched_yield()`. The consequences of
>   this call are a little different, and possibly more severe than under
>   Windows.

Source: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/yield.shtml

Comment: Not just this contex.  When "current thread" appears in the documentation of almost _any_ method it means "the thread that calls the method".

Answer (score 4):

The current thread is affected, i.e. the thread that calls the method.

> Isn't it be more clear to say myThread.yield() instead of Thread.yield()? Does anyone have ideas about this?

No it isn't. It's a static method, and it's well-specified. In this case it would also convey the opposite of what actually happens.

But it's also pointless. `yield()` functions haven't done anything useful since the 16-bit part of Windows 98. Your thread will get rescheduled anyway as the scheduler sees fit.

Answer (score 0):

The main thread will be affected.
You always can do `Thread.currentThread().getName()` to get the current thread name.
also you can do

```
 Thread.currentThread().yield()
```

the other thread is running the run method until it finished and than exit.

Comment: It's called `currentThread()` (with a 't' and not a 'd'), and it's a function - not a field - so you should put parentheses `()` behind it to invoke the function.